# Python 2.6.1: Checking if imports exist

Tags: python, macos, python-module, python-import

I have written a utility script for some of my colleagues' Mac OSX with Python 2.6.1. Since they don't have all the required modules installed, I have a try-except import clause:

```python
try:
    import argparse
except ImportError:
    print "argparse module missing: Please run 'sudo easy_install argparse'"
    sys.exit(1)
```

I'm pretty sure there are more elegant ways to handle this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best shot is to freeze your python code with all modules needed and distribute it as binary; it worked for me with Windows and Linux, however on Linux,  make sure you have a compatible glibc version

There are some freeze tools for Mac OS X, but I have not used them. I only used Windows and Linux tools.

check out this link for more info

http://hackerboss.com/how-to-distribute-commercial-python-applications/

Answer (score 4):

That is the common idiom but you can use `setuptools` and [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) to automate the installation of dependencies ([example](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie/blob/master/setup.py)).

Comment: best solution, cause it is scalable, and could make user live easier in case of several modules missing

Comment: By default (when installing packages system-wide) yes, but you can use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/) to create a completely  isolated Python environment in your home folder and install the package there.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the best way to do it. The same approach is for example used to select different json libraries depending on what's installed on the machine:

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

Comment: such things can be done only for exclusive cases, not for argparse like in his example

Comment: It was just to give a use-case of such syntax, in support to the claim that this is the right way to do it. I know that it just apply to very few examples